# restoring tensorflow graph which uses shuffle_batch hangs forever

Tags: python, tensorflow, restore

I have a tensorflow code that uses tf.train.shuffle_batch for the training part. I read some forums and I got the idea to use these lines to separate between the input pipeline that uses queues and the inference part that should just use one single image:

```
 ima=queue_loader.images
 is_just_one = tf.placeholder(dtype=bool,shape=(),name='is_just_one')
 imgs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (1, height, width, 1), name='imgs')
 images = tf.cond(is_just_one, lambda:imgs, lambda:ima)
```

then I just specify in feed_dict is_just_one:False during my training. I save the model after each epoch with:

```
saver.save(sess, checkpoint_path, global_step=ep+1)
```

After having a checkpoint file, I run the freeze.py code in this way:

```
python freeze.py --model_dir=checkpoints --output_node_names=imgs,is_just_one,prediction
```

Then: I try to restore my model with this code:

```
imn=tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None,None,1))
imno=tf.image.per_image_standardization(imn)
X=io.imread("test.png")
with tf.Session() as sesss:
  X=sesss.run(imno,feed_dict={imn:X[...,0,None]})

with tf.gfile.GFile("checkpoints/frozen_model.pb", "rb") as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def,name='import')

for i in range(2):
    with tf.Session(graph=graph,config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True)) as sess:
        act_map =graph.get_tensor_by_name("import/prediction:0")
        is_just_one = graph.get_tensor_by_name("import/is_just_one:0")
        inputs = graph.get_tensor_by_name("import/imgs:0")
        mapp=sess.run(act_map,feed_dict={is_just_one:True,inputs:X[None,:,:,None]})
```

What happens when I run my code is that it hangs forever, device placement is:

```
 I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:872] import/shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue: (RandomShuffleQueueV2)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
```

So, if I understand correctly, the saved node associated to the tf.train.shuffle_batch is waiting for inputs, and since I don't feed it then it hangs forever.

what is going wrong with this? Is there a way to ignore that node and just feed the image in the graph as usual?

Thank you very much for your precious help

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! It's quite simple indeed, but was giving me very hard headaches. To solve this problem one just needs to define something like:

```
  input_placeholder = tf.placeholder_with_default(image, [None, None, None, 1],name="inputs")
```

where image is the image from queue and shuffle_batch. The structure tf.placeholder_with_default specifies that if no value is passed to this node in feed_dict, then its value is just "image". When I restore my frozen model, then I just use feed_dict in the usual way giving something to this placeholder, and all works. I think in this way all the rubbish nodes concerning shuffle_batch are just left apart if the value of the placeholder is specified. Good to know.